# How to get EXIF from Cordova ImagePicker plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker plugin in an Ionic project to get pictures.

How can I get EXIF (Date Taken) of the pictures chosen ?
The imagepicker creates a copy of the chosen images without EXIF.

Comment: this was an issue reported on the plugin forum https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker/issues/26

Comment: what is your purpose behind that ? may be we can help with some work around if you explain end goal and issue.

Comment: I am trying to get the "Date Taken" from the picture.
End goal is a JSON object with the image as base64 and date taken